# How to write data as multiple records on NFC tag in Android?

Tags: java, android, tags, nfc, ndef

I followed [this](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2016/01/nfc-tag-writer-android.html) to write data to an NFC Tag.

This is my [MainActivity](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/blob/master/NFCWriter/app/src/main/java/com/survivingwithandroid/nfcwriter/MainActivity.java) and my [NFCManager](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Surviving-with-android/blob/master/NFCWriter/app/src/main/java/com/survivingwithandroid/nfcwriter/NFCManager.java).

I successfully write data to the NFC tag.

But its placing data in `Record 0` only. There are no other records created on the tag.

However, I want to place the data into multiple records like `Record 0`, `Record 1`, `Record 2`, `Record 3`.

So I modified `MainActivity` like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nfcMger = new NFCManager(this);

    v = findViewById(R.id.mainLyt);

    final EditText et0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnt0);
    final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnt1);
    final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnt2);
    final EditText et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnt3);

    FloatingActionButton btn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String ct0 = et0.getText().toString();
            String ct1 = et1.getText().toString();
            String ct2 = et2.getText().toString();
            String ct3 = et3.getText().toString();


            message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct0, "id");
            message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct1, "name");
            message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct2, "role");
            message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct3, "level");


            if (message != null) {

                dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Tag NFC Tag please");
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

But when I use this and write data to the tag it stores only a `Record 0` on the tag. There is no other record.

I only get the last saved data in `Record 0`:

[image]

My expectation is to write data to multiple records like this:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me how to insert the data to multiple records (`Record 0`, `Record 1`, `Record 2`, `Record 3`)?

**Update**

with reference of user@Michael Roland I have updated my code I got this error

[image]

Here I followed [Method NdefRecord.createTextRecord(“en” , “string”) not working below API level 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875323/method-ndefrecord-createtextrecorden-string-not-working-below-api-level) And I have given the `NdefRecord` method but its showing error when I Give same for the `message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {`

so out side the message its not a error but I want it inside the message

thanks @Michael Roland for the Support

Answer (score 2):

You only find one message containing one record on the tag because that's what you do in your code. Here you create one NDEF message containing one URI record:

```
message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct0, "id");
```

Right on the next line you overwrite the previously stored message (referenced in `message`) with another NDEF message containing only one URI record:

```
message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct1, "name");
```

And on the next two lines you do that same thing again:

```
message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct2, "role");
message =  nfcMger.createUriMessage(ct3, "level");
```

Consequently, only the last line will effectively store an NDEF message in `message`.

You probably then store that message onto the tag<sup>1</sup>.

However, given the above screenshot, you would probably rather want to create one NDEF message containing 4 Text records. E.g. like this:

```
message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
        NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", "Text 1"),
        NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", "Text 2"),
        NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", "Text 3"),
        NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en", "Text 4"),
});
```

Btw. since `createTextRecord()` is only available starting with API level 21, you might want to check out [Method NdefRecord.createTextRecord("en" , "string") not working below API level 21](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37875323/2425802) for lower API levels.

Also note that Text records are intended for storing human-readable textual data. For storing machine-readable information, other records (such as the NFC Forum External Type) would be more suitable.

---

<sup>1</sup>) Though, you seem to be rather reluctant to present a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but believe that readers of your question would want to browse through tons of unnecessary code on GitHub to understand your problem. Note that that code might not even exist for the whole lifetime of the question and once that source code disappears, your question will be mostly useless for others.

**Finally, note that if your really observed one record of type text/plain with the textual value "junior" on the tag, you certainly did not use the code from GitHub without further modifications since the code that you revealed would have created one (malformed?) URI record.**

Comment: Thanks for the Updated answer But I am getting error at `message` because I have declared it as `private NdefMessage message = null;` so I modified it to `private NdefRecord[] message = null;`  and also at `createTextRecord` hence I am using Api 19 as min can you update your answer for api 19

Comment: @MLN See [Method NdefRecord.createTextRecord(“en” , “string”) not working below API level 21](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37875323/2425802) for a way to get `createTextRecord()` on API levels below 21.

Comment: Please check my updated question so that it may help to solve my issue thanks

Comment: @MLN Did you read the linked answer? Simply remove the `NdefRecord.` part from `NdefRecord.createTextRecord()` to use the `createTextRecord()` method that you seem to have added to your activity.